# Cannot maximize snipping tool to 100% (full screen)

Tags: windows-7, snipping

I am having a problem with snipping tool. I can't not maximize snipping tool to 100% (full screen) as you can see in the picture below.

Hope someone know how to fix this. I am using Windows 7 64 bit. The problem has just happened recently.

[image]

1. Before using maximize

[image]

2. After using maximize, the windows is not full screen

Answer (score 0):

It seems to go full screen only the the type selected is free-form,window or full screen snip. Not when rectangular snip is selected.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't understand what you meant to say here.

Comment: When you open snipping tool, click on the small arrow beside the 'new' button. You will get more options for the type of snip.

Comment: It’s probably related to the resulting image size, not the capture mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just explore the more snipping options available there.

[image: You have more options like this.]

'Full-Screen snip' takes the full screen screen shot.

By the way, a simple way to do that is  `Alt + PrintScreen` key, and the full screen-shot will be taken and will be in the clipboard ready to be pasted. This also works with windowed applications.